# POST with POSTMAN using CKAN API

Tags: api, post, postman, ckan

I'm trying to send a POST using Postman and CKAN API but I'm not sure what to include in the URL, headers and body. This is what I have tried. Can someone can help me out with the format? What to include in URL, headers and body?
[In the image you can see that I send the URL without / as mention in another post but still it does not work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VUQQ.jpg)

[I included the API key in the headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqyqu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call the datastore_upsert action. The action URL should be 
http://demo.ckan.org/api/action/datastore_upsert. In the headers tab, you should add Authorization key and the API key as a value e.g Authorization 2131238ac-32fs-4f19-8ac9-d4af5esadasd2. Then inside the body, you should add the datastore_upsert action [required parameters](https://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-2.6.3/maintaining/datastore.html#ckanext.datastore.logic.action.datastore_upsert).

Comment: I set up the URL, API Key and body but still  I get an error "Bad request - JSON error: Invalid request. Please use POST method for your request " URL: http://demo.ckan.org/api/action/datastore_upsert
HEADER: api-key  8bee1244-8dc6-494e-9b02-36587730df46
Body: {"resource_id":"728bcd40-320c-4328-99cc-a6a0753eb9cf", "method": "insert", "records": [{"AccX": 42, "AccY": 41, "AccZ":43} ],"force": "True"}

Comment: In my experience, CKAN API validation error messages aren't always correct. For example, I wouldn't be surprised if there was something else wrong with your request.